# Model a tree that belongs to a row in another table

Tags: hierarchy

Given the tables "users" and "nodes" (which will contain an adjacency list tree) what is the best way to link these tables (each user has a tree).

Putting the column "user_id" in the "nodes" table seems very ineffective to me, but I couldn't find other solution.

Comment: Each tree belongs to exactly one user? If yes, you can add a joining table with 2 columns: `(root_node_id, user_id)`. The primary key will be `(root_node_id)` and `(user_id)` will be a foreign key to `users`.